# How to get the access token after successful signin-oidc?

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, openid-connect, asp.net-core-3.1

I have this configured in my Azure Active Directory App Registrations. After the successful signin-oidc the response has id_token in the formdata, but I'm also looking for the access_token as it is checked in my configuration.

[image]

Comment: How did you request the token? Which authentication flow is used?

Comment: please see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition

Comment: What scopes did you ask for? Perhaps you didn't ask for the access token?

Comment: If my answer is helpful for you, you can accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in.). See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You may not set the **token** response when executing the login request, try to set the **response_type** to **id_token+token**, you will get id_token and access token.

Execute the request in the browser:

```
GET https://login.microsoftonline.com/e4c9ab4e-bd27-40d5-8459-230ba2axxxxx/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=305c9958-8f6f-4bcf-a4ec-06cb4faxxxxx
&response_type=id_token+token
&redirect_uri=https://jwt.ms
&response_mode=fragment
&scope=openid+profile+email 
&state=12345
&nonce=678910
```

Please see: [Get an access token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-protocols-oidc#protocol-diagram-access-token-acquisition)